# Will putting new subs and amp in car drain my battery

Tags: audio, battery-drain

I have a 99 Acura 3.2 TL with a Napa legend 75 battery would putting a 1000 watt amp and 2 15 subs hurt my car?

Answer (score 3):

Your question title doesn't quite match the body... but I'll answer both:

Simply put, this shouldn't harm your car - but that said, there are some things you may need to do:

- Check that you have good connections to ground - a 1000W amp can draw a lot of current
- You'll want a high current cable with inline fuse from your battery +ve to your amp. A sub being driven hard will draw more than your average car's wiring loom can cope with
- Check the alternator is well maintained and gives a charging current of greater than the current draw of the amp :-)
- If you plan on playing your music loud when parked with the engine off, seriously consider getting an uprated battery or maybe even a second battery. It's embarrassing how fast you can drain a battery at a beach party...

Comment: Thank you do you recommend any specific battery to get if I get secondary?

Comment: Many places do "winter" or "heavy duty" batteries. I have various devices and a 650w amp in my car, and I run off a winter battery that is double the capacity of a normal battery - can't remember exact amp/hours, but that was the selling point for me